# How to set up access to MSSQL 2005 Database Mail?

Tags: sql-server, roles, database-mail

I've just setup Database mail within MSSQL 2005. I have been able to send email from an administrator account on the server and through a SQL Server Agent job. But, I unable to send email when I tried to send email via a login that just has access to a database for our web application.

What is the best way to set up access to Database Mail?

I have 2 senerios where I want to send email.

1. Schedule a job through SQL Server Agent to run a Stored Procedure that does some process and then sends an email. (this hasn't been a problem)
2. Have a stored procedure invoked from a web application that calls another stored procedure which could send an email. (this is were my permissions issue is)

***Possible Solutions***

1. The only way that I have found to grant permission to a login is to map the login to the **msdb** database and grant the **public** and **DatabaseMailUserRole**. This really concerns me as I would assume that this gives to much access to the **msdb** database.
2. Store the email I want to send in a table and then have a SQL Server Agent job look at that table every so often to send any queued emails. This way the database login for the web application does not execute the [msdb].[dbo].[sp_ send _dbmail] call and thus does not need any permission to the **msdb** database.

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Interesting. Hope you'll get answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a stored procedure **WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER** option so it runs in the context of the owner rather than the caller.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SendMail]
(
    @To nvarchar(1000),
    @Subject nvarchar(100),
    @Body nvarchar(max)
)
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
    exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'MailProfile', 
                @recipients = @To, 
                @subject = @Subject, 
                @body = @Body
END
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but this didn't work for me. The login that is the owner of the database for our application is a login that I have successfully sent email from. When I use the code recommended; I get an "EXECUTE permission denied on object" error.

Comment: GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.sp_SendMail TO User1

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same but executing

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.sp_SendMail TO User1
```

is not fixing this issue. Only thing which is making this procedure to work is not adding

```
EXECUTE AS OWNER
```

(I'm creating it with "WITH ENCRYPTION" only) and adding user which will be running this procedure to msdb DatabaseMailUserRole role:

```
USE msdb
GO
EXEC sp_adduser @loginame='USERNAME', @grpname='DatabaseMailUserRole'
GO
```

Thanks